# Remove table rows using jQuery but prevent remove the first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using jQuery to remove table rows - my script works ok but I don't want the button to be able to remove the very first table row. Can anyone suggest how this is done?

```
    $("#remove").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();        
    $("table tr:last").remove();
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if ($("table tr").length != 1) {
     $("table tr:last").remove();
}
```

Comment: all great answers.. wish i could accept them all :) (they should probably add that feature!)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$("tr:last:not(:first)").remove();
```

You don't need the `table` selector as all rows are inside tables, but it might be useful to specify the table element from which you want to remove (avoiding side effects if you later would add other tables).

Example: Remove all rows from `$table` except the first:

```
$("tr:not(:first)", $table).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gt()` and `not()`:

```
$('table').find('tr:gt(0):last').remove();
```

This finds all rows with an index greater than 0, `gt(0)` and selects the last row, `:last` and then removes that element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XhtC8/

If you wanted to remove all rows but the first then you can remove `:last`:

```
$('table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#remove").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();        
    $("table tr:not(':first')").remove();
    i++;
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aGukb/

Comment: omg.. so simple & elegent - brilliant stuff Ayman thanks for that!

Comment: I meant "`:first`" by the way!

Comment: @Zabs: You've commented that two different answers work for you, but the two answers do different things. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: both do the same thing but the raminson effort looks the simpler one even though Ayman's one is less code. Either way thanks :-)
Sorry @amnotiam you was right i am sorry

Comment: @Zabs: Unless you never have more than 2 rows, they do not do the same thing. I wouldn't have said they're different if they weren't.

Comment: Sorry.. i meant to say... the first effort by Raminson is the one I am trying to acheive :) Long day!